# how to programmatically exit the desktop app flutter

Tags: flutter, desktop

In context of Flutter desktop app, some of instructions does not work on the same way that mobile app. The control of flow app seems to be in this situation.

those issues does not work on desktop context app :

- `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');`
- `exit(0)`